# gemischtes Geschlecht Mitbewohner

Tags: noun, gender, grammatical-number, gender-neutrality

> John ist mein Mitbewohner.
> Anna ist meine Mitbewohnerin.
> John und Jason sind meine Mitbewohner (?)
> John und Anna sind ???

Können Sie mir mit dem fehlenden Wort oder mit Korrekturen helfen?

Answer (score 10):

Die natürliche Art, den Satz zu formulieren, ist

> John und Anna sind meine Mitbewohner.

Der Plural des maskulinen Wortes *Mitbewohner* bezieht sich auch auf gemischte Gruppen. In der aktuellen Auflage der Duden-Grammatik wird dies als *sexusindifferenter Gebrauch* bezeichnet.

Die Form *Mitbewohnerinnen* (Plural der von *Mitbewohner* abgeleiteten femininen Form *Mitbewohnerin*) ist dagegen *sexusspezifisch*, bezieht sich also auf Gruppen, die ausschließlich aus weiblichen Personen bestehen und kommt deshalb hier nicht infrage.

Meines Erachtens gibt es hier einen grammatischen Grund, die Kritik am sexusindifferenten Gebrauch von Nomen – also das Thema der geschlechtergerechten Sprache – zu ignorieren: Im Beispielsatz werden die Bezugspersonen ([Referenten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referent_(Linguistik))) *John und Anna* als Subjekt durch ihre Namen eingeführt. Das Nomen *Mitbewohner* fungiert dagegen als [Prädikativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativum), das dem Subjekt eine Eigenschaft zuschreibt. Da die Referenten schon durch das Subjekt eingeführt werden, ist der sexusindifferente Gebrauch des Nomens *Mitbewohner* nicht zu kritisieren, da keine Informationen über das Geschlecht der Referenten unterschlagen werden.

Anders wäre dies in folgendem Fall:

> Wir laden alle Hausbewohner zu unserem Fest ein.

Die eingeladenen Personen werden durch das Akkusativobjekt *alle Hausbewohner* eingeführt. Hier greift die Kritik, die der Idee der geschlechtergerechten Sprache zugrunde liegt: Es ist offen, ob die Phrase sexusindifferent (Männer und Frauen) oder sexusspezifisch (nur Männer) zu verstehen ist; und wenn sie sexusindifferent zu verstehen ist, sind die Frauen an dieser Stelle in dem Sinne nur mitgemeint, daß man die Form eben theoretisch auch sexusspezifisch verstehen kann.

Je nachdem, wie man diese Kritik bewertet, kann man zu einer Formulierung mit Gender-Gap wie der folgenden wechseln.

> Wir laden alle Hausbewohner_innen zu unserem Fest ein.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119880/discussion-on-answer-by-david-vogt-gemischtes-geschlecht-mitbewohner).

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt hier im Deutschen verschiedene Möglichkeiten. Traditionell wird für diese Szenarien das **generische Maskulinum** verwendet, in diesem Fall also: *Mitbewohner*.

Das generische Maskulinum steht aber stark in der Kritik, und im Deutschen hat ein Sprachwandel hin zur gendergerechten Sprache eingesetzt, von dem gegenwärtig noch offen ist, wie weit er sich realisieren wird. Der Streit dreht sich unter anderem darum, ob das generische Maskulinum nicht-männliche Adressat*innen oder Referent*innen ausreichend sichtbar macht. Eine Sprache, die nicht-männliche Adressat*innen explizit sichtbar macht, wird als "gendergerechter Sprachgebrauch" bezeichnet.

Neben akademischen Institutionen hat die gendergerechte Sprache, die versucht, auch nicht-maskuline Referenten explizit sprachlich sichtbar zu machen, auch in den Duden und auch in einige Sender des öffentlich-rechtlichen Rundfunks Einzug gehalten. Dabei haben sich verschiedene Möglichkeiten etabliert: das Binnen-I (*MitbewohnerInnen*), der Gendergap (*Mitbewohner_innen*), der Gender-Star (*Mitbewohner*innen*) oder der Doppelpunkt (*Mitbewohner:innen*).

Weitere Details zu dieser öffentlich breit geführten Debatte weiß der Wikipedia-Eintrag [Geschlechtergerechte Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache).

Nun etwas detaillierter zu deinen beiden Fällen:

## Beide sind männlich

### Generisches Maskulinum

> John und Jason sind meine Mitbewohner.

### Spezifisches Maskulinum

> John und Jason sind meine Mitbewohner.

Diese Form kann auch als spezifisches Maskulinum verstanden werden. Generisches und spezifisches Maskulinum sind in diesem Fall nicht unterscheidbar. Das ist gerade der Hauptkritikpunkt am generischen Maskulinum.

### Genderneutraler Ausdruck

Man könnte auch sagen:

> John und Jason sind meine MitbewohnerInnen / Mitbewohner*innen Mitbewohner_innen / Mitbewohner:innen.

In diesen Varianten wird das Maskulinum durch eine Form ersetzt, die das Geschlecht explizit offen lässt, also eine eindeutig genderneutrale Formulierung gewählt. (Verteidiger des generischen Maskulinums meinen, dass auch das generische Maskulinum genderneutral sei, aber die genannten Formen sind in jedem Fall unmissverständlicher genderneutral.)

Dass John und Jason Männer sind, wird in dieser Formulierung eher als "zufälliger" Fakt, als kontingent, dargestellt -- also als eine Tatsache, die auch anders sein könnte. Die Bezeichnung legt den Fokus auf die Tatsache, "dass John und Jason mit mir zusammenwohnen", und rückt die Information, "ob bzw. dass John und Jason männlich sind", stärker in den Hintergrund.

## Beide sind verschiedenen Geschlechts

### Generisches Maskulinum

> John und Anna sind meine Mitbewohner.

Falls Anna nicht männlich ist, würde dieser Satz als generisches Maskulinum interpretiert werden. Diese Variante ist die umstrittene Form des generischen Maskulinums.

### Nennung beider Geschlechter

> John und Anna sind meine Mitbewohner und Mitbewohnerinnen.

Eine Möglichkeit, die Mehrdeutigkeit des generischen Maskulinums aufzuheben, ist es beide Geschlechter zu spezifizieren.

Da von jedem Geschlecht nur eine Person vertreten ist, ist hier die Verwendung des Singulars passender:

> John und Anna sind mein Mitbewohner und meine Mitbewohnerin.

### Gendergerechte Ausdrucksformen

#### Moderne, eigens eingeführte Varianten

> John und Anna sind meine MitbewohnerInnen / Mitbewohner*innen Mitbewohner_innen / Mitbewohner:innen.

Das sind genderneutale Varianten. Sie lassen insbesondere offen, mit welchem Geschlecht sich John und Anna identifizieren, und insbesondere auch, ob sie sich mit ihrem Geschlecht außerhalb der binären männlich-weiblich-Kategorisierung einordnen.

#### Umformulierung

Man kann den Satz auch so umformulieren, dass er das strittige Substantiv gar nicht mehr enthält. Dies ist auch ein Vorschlag der gendergerechten Sprache. Eine Möglichkeit wäre:

> John und Anna wohnen mit mir zusammen.

Auf diese Weise würde man sowohl der Forderung nach einer gendersensiblen Sprache nachkommen, als auch einem sprachlichen Traditionalismus entgegenkommen, der die Einführung der obigen Schreibweisen mit traditionalistischen Argumenten ablehnt.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119881/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathan-scholbach-gemischtes-geschlecht-mitbewohner).

Answer (score 3):

Die natürliche Art, den Satz zu formulieren, ist

> Das sind John und Anna. Wir wohnen zusammen.

In Sprachen wie Englisch benutzt man wohl tatsächlich Formulierungen wie *John is my roommate* "John ist mein Mitbewohner". Im Deutschen verwenden die meisten Sprecher meistens eine andere Wendung. Mitbewohner ist im Deutschen eher ein [seltenes](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Mitbewohner) Wort und wird überwiegend in der Schriftsprache verwendet.

Was die Frage betrifft, wie man Personen unterschiedlichen Geschlechts in einem Begriff zusammenfasst, so befinden wir uns gegenwärtig in einer Umbruchsphase. Traditionell wurde hier das [generische Maskulinum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generisches_Maskulinum) verwendet, bei dem die grammatisch männliche Form eines Wortes für Personen beiderlei Geschlechts verwendet werden kann. Dagegen gibt es heute Bemühungen, die Sprache [geschlechtergerecht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache) zu gestalten. Im Zuge dieser Bemühungen wurden unterschiedliche Vorschläge gemacht – männliche und weibliche Form verwenden, Gendersternchen, geschlechtslose Formulierungen usw. – von denen sich bislang keine durchgesetzt hat.

Geht man von den heute gültigen Rechtschreib- und Grammatikregeln aus, so ist die korrekte Form das generische Maskulinum:

> John und Anna sind meine Mitbewohner.

Dies ist auch für die Mehrheit der Sprecher noch die korrekte Form. In den Medien, vor allem [im öffentlich-rechtlichen Rundfunk](https://www.prisma.de/news/ZDF-antwortet-auf-Kritik-an-gesprochenen-Gender-Sternchen,27433812), und im akademischen Kontext verbreiten sich jedoch zunehmend gegenderte Formen. Für diese Sprecher könnte sich folgende Form richtig anfühlen:

> John und Anna sind meine Mitbewohner*innen. (Das "Gendersternchen" wird als Glottisverschluss gesprochen, d.h. wie eine Pause im Wortinneren.)

Gegen gegenderte Formen gibt es jedoch auch einen breiten Widerstand in der Bevölkerung.

Comment: Das mit dem 'breiten Widerstand' scheint zuzutreffen, aber nix Genaues weiß man da nicht - jedenfalls wird das Gendern nicht breitflächig praktiziert, sondern ist milieugebunden. Ob die Studis das in der Kneipe auch machen? Die von dir als 'natürlich' genannte Formulierung ist tatsächlich naheliegend und nicht so störreiz-trächtig wie gegenderte Sprechweisen, nur: Auch das müsste man sich antrainieren, alle eventuell genderdiskriminierenden Redeweisen 'weiträumig zu umfahren', also seine Sätze 5 Sekunden vorher zu planen und sich für Gewohnt-Generisches immer etwas anderes zu überlegen.